# Div not floating correctly after div with css flipping animation because of absolute elements

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create css flipping animation using some tutorials on web.
Most tutorial only talk about cases where height of the elements is known. 
For e.g in  this tutorial
http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip
The height for flip-container, front and back is set to 480px.

```
.flip-container, .front, .back {
   width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}
```

If I add any div after flip-container, it should follow normal document flow and float after flip-container. But, what if, I don't know the size of front and back elements, or lets say I want it to scale dynamically based on the content, then I'm running into issue. Because making .front and . back "absolute" puts them out of document flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/zk81h12u/4/

```
<div class="flip-container ">
   ....
</div
<div class="icon-container">
  icon
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to correctly float "icon-container" after the flip-container. Right now it just ends up on top of flip-container".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example you showed, the `.front` and the `.back` always have the same height, right? Even if it's dynamic. So, you can use the `position: absolute;` only in the back element.

```css
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

**You can remove these properties, in this case, the "back" part will overwrite the content, but it will still working well.**

---

I've created a more detailed version and I did a general improvement in your code, take a look:

```css
.flip-container,
.flip-container .front,
.flip-container .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

.flip-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1000;
  position: relative;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.active .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container .flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-container .front,
.flip-container .back {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1em solid #61AE24;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.flip-container .front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.flip-container .back {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      Hello! I'm on the front part.
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      CSS animations are a lot of fun; the beauty of them is that through many simple properties, you can create anything from an elegant fade in to a WTF-Pixar-would-be-proud effect. One CSS effect somewhere in between is the CSS flip effect, whereby there's content on both the front and back of a given container. This tutorial will show you show to create that effect in as simple a manner as possible.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Content flow.
</div>
```

---

**Otherwise, you may consider the use of JavaScript.**

```js
var flipContainer, flipContainerBack, flipContainerFront;

flipContainer = document.querySelector('.flip-container');
flipContainerFront = document.querySelector('.flip-container .front');
flipContainerBack = document.querySelector('.flip-container .back');

function setFlipContainerFrontHeight() {
  flipContainer.style.height = flipContainerFront.offsetHeight + 'px';
};

function setFlipContainerBackHeight() {
  flipContainer.style.height = flipContainerBack.offsetHeight + 'px';
};

setFlipContainerFrontHeight();
flipContainer.onmouseover = setFlipContainerBackHeight;
flipContainer.onmouseout = setFlipContainerFrontHeight;
```

```css
.flip-container,
.flip-container .front,
.flip-container .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;

  -ms-transition: height 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.6s;
  -o-transition: height 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
  transition: height 0.6s;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.active .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container .flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-container .front,
.flip-container .back {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1em solid #61AE24;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flip-container .front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.flip-container .back {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      Hello! I'm on the front part.
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      CSS animations are a lot of fun; the beauty of them is that through many simple properties, you can create anything from an elegant fade in to a WTF-Pixar-would-be-proud effect. One CSS effect somewhere in between is the CSS flip effect, whereby there's content on both the front and back of a given container. This tutorial will show you show to create that effect in as simple a manner as possible.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Content flow.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for creating more detailed version. This is my problem that the .front and the .back are NOT always have the same height. That's why I want to avoid giving it a height so it can scale depending on content. I thought of giving it a min-height too but it doesn't work. I think it is the parent flip-container that doesn't scale according to child elements i.e .back. I have just added added more content on the back and you will see the problem I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/1ejkd9ro/

Comment: sorry, it is .back which is not scaling in this case

Comment: @jas, you'll need to choose between `.front` and `.back`, one of them will determine the `.flip-container` height. Otherwise, I believe it'll only be possible using JavaScript.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by choosing between  .front and .back ?

Comment: @jas One of them will be responsible for the `.flip-container` height. See in the end of the my answer, I updated it with an example using JavaScript.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for providing the solution. You are right, I guess it is not possible to do it without javascript